# iOS custom views in xib files

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I usually create my custom views programatically and have them intended to be initialised programatically as well with custom init methods (e.g. initWithFrame:SomeParam:OtherParam). Is it possible to use such custom views in combination with a xib file? That is, having a parent xib file which has various of these custom views as subviews in which these subviews may need to use a different init method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you add custom views into a xib file, you can't use a custom initializer. They will all be initialized using `initWithCoder`.

Typically you'd do any set up in a common method called from there, or in `awakeFromNib`.

If you need to set any custom properties on your view which originate from outside it, do it in `viewDidLoad` of your view controller.

Comment: If I need to do sth before viewDidLoad of my view controller, how to do it ? So example ... My view is used to show one page of a book.Without custom init method such as initWithPage:page, at the same time I also use the storyboard.

Comment: Before viewDidLoad, your view doesn't exist. Just move the setup you do in initWith... into a different method and make whatever changes you need there, after you set the property.

Answer (score 6):

Get the view's xib initialized the regular way and using the reference  do the custom settings. this part can be put in the init method like this-

```
     -(void)initfunction{
        UIView *containerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myView"  owner:self    options:nil] lastObject];
       containerView.property1 = xyz;//Customization
       containerView.property2= abc;//Customization
       containerView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,z,p);//Customization
       [rootView addSubview:containerView];


   }
```

the point is when we use a xib we do not initialize explicitly, the `xib` utility functions return an initialized object(of `UIView`), after one gets the `UIView` object, he/she can use the initialized object as just a regular object to make further custom changes.

Answer (score 2):

of-course it is possible. drag a uiview in the xib not inside the default view. then make a `IBOutlet UIView *myCustomView;` and then connect it with the other view. when u want to show this view add this as `[self.view addSubview:myCustomView];` when want to remove it

`[myCustomView removeFromSuperView];`

[image]

Comment: So...how about initWithSomeValue:value function?

Comment: This won't work if you want to share say a custom header view across multiple XIB files... You would have to redefine it exactly in each xib

Answer (score 0):

The UINib (iOS) and NSNib (OS X) classes provide better performance in situations where you want to create multiple copies of a nib file’s contents. The normal nib-loading process involves reading the nib file from disk and then instantiating the objects it contains. However, with the UINib and NSNib classes, the nib file is read from disk once and the contents are stored in memory. Because they are in memory, creating successive sets of objects takes less time because it does not require accessing the disk.

1. Create one-view xib file: Right-click on the project -> New File -> User Interface -> View  (e.g. you will have "MyView.xib")
2. Fill the view using Interface Builder
3. Add next method to you parent component

   ```
   static UINib *nib = nil;

   - (UIView*)createNewViewFromNib: (NSString *)nibFileName
   {
       if( nib == nil) {
           nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:nibFileName bundle:nil ];
       }

       // Unarchiving objects from the nib. You can do it multiple times to create a number of objects from same nib.
       NSArray*    topLevelObjs = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];

       if (topLevelObjs == nil)
       {
           NSLog(@"Warning! Could not load nib file.\n");
           return nil;
       }
       // We have only one view in the nib.
       return [topLevelObjs objectAtIndex:0];
   }
   ```
4. Use next line of code to instantiate you view with reusable nib object:

   ```
   UIView *item = [self createNewViewFromNib:@"MyView"];
   // [self.view addSubview:item];
   ```